# Partial specialization of nested template template class

Tags: c++11, templates, c++14, template-specialization, partial-specialization

I am currently struggeling with partial template specialization of a template template (template ) class. I know we can realize the following problem with inheritance but the goal is to use only templates and template specialization.

Let's consider this piece of code:

```
template< typename T >
struct V4;
template< >
struct V4< float > {
    using point_type = std::array< float, 4 >;
};
template< typename T >
struct V12;
template< >
struct V12< int > {
    using point_type = std::array< int, 12 >;
};

template< typename T, template< typename = T > class IM >
struct Rectangle;
template< template< typename > class IM >
struct Rectangle< float, IM > {
    float get( size_t i ) { /*...*/ }
};

template< typename T, template< typename = T > class IM >
struct Polygon;
template< template< typename > class IM >
struct Polygon< int, IM > {
    float get( size_t i ) { /*...*/ }
};
```

The classes V2 and V12 can be considered as some kind of a wrapper classes for builtin-types or aggregates. The classes Rectangle and Polygon uses V2 or V12 and are partial specialized.
So far so good. We can use this like the following:

```
Rectangle< float, V4 > a;
std::cout << a.get(1) << "\n";
```

Now what we want to achieve is a class which encapsulates some calculations on the introduces structs for instance. It should be called like this:

```
std::cout << CalculateSomething< Rectangle< float, V4 > >::doIt( ) << "\n";
```

CalculateSomething should be partial specializable regarding to wether it works with an Rectangle or an Polygon. So a possible specialization should look like this:

```
template< typename T >
struct CalculateCenter< Rectangle< T, V2 >, T > {
    static T doIt( ) {
        /*...*/
    }
};
template< typename T >
struct CalculateCenter< Polygon< T, V12 >, T > {
    static T doIt( ) {
        /*...*/
    }
};
```

The question now is: How to declare the template class CalculateCenter?

Thanks in advance

Comment: *"We can use this like the following: `Rectangle< int, V4 > a;`"* No we cannot - there is no definition for `Rectangle<T>` where `T` is not `float`

Comment: Changed the code. now it should work

Comment: You may want to change one of your tags to [c++] per the request on the c++14 tag wiki, you will likely get more visibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer seems rather straightforward:

```
template < class T >
struct CalculateCenter;

template< typename T >
struct CalculateCenter< Rectangle< T, V2 > > {
    static T doIt( ) {
        /*...*/
    }
};

template< typename T >
struct CalculateCenter< Polygon< T, V12 > > {
    static T doIt( ) {
        /*...*/
    }
};
```

[[Live example]](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/82250a440ddc7fc0)

Comment: Thanks! Did not see the forrest for the trees. :/